# Upgrading Entity Framework package with SqlLite integration tests throws SqlLiteException

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

In the process of upgrading our version of Entity Framework from 2.2.6 to 6.0.12 many of the integration tests have broken.  These use an in memory sqlite database.

The error revolves around migrations and a database function that was added in a migration.  This function is used to define a Computed Column in the dbContext `OnModelCreating()` method.  During unit test set up we run

```
 _dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
 _dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Calling `EnsureCreated` results in this exception being thrown:
`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 1: 'near "(": syntax error'.`

Stack tracing this, it occurs `OnModelCreating` when we call.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyObject>()
            .Property(p => p.LinkId)
            .HasComputedColumnSql("Schema.fn_link_id([Id])");
```

The syntax for this appears to be correct, so despite the exception error message, this seems to be occurring because the function does not exist as `EnsureCreated()` does not run a migration.

So my question is **what is the best method to update an in memory sqlite database to include a database function that was added during a migration** and fix this error?

Things I've attempted:

1. Replacing the call to `.EnsureCreated()` with a call to `.Migrate()`.  This doesn't work because of the limitations of SqLite migrations, being unable to AlterColumns etc.  A work around exists where I could rewrite all of the existing migrations by hand to accommodate sqlite, but I'd like to avoid having to do this for 5+ years of migrations.
2. Use `.Migrate()` and also change the database provider to a local instance of SqlServer.  This resolves the issue and the unit tests pass locally.  However, this would result in additional overhead and considerations in our CICD pipeline which we'd like to avoid.
3. Create the function in the test itself to bypass a need for migrations - Results in the same unhelpful syntax error:

```
var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
connection.Open();

connection.CreateFunction("Schema.fn_link_id", (int Id) => Guid.NewGuid());

var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                .UseSqlite(connection)
                .Options;
```